# gspread find in_column list index out of range

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to find an item inside a worksheet using gspread but only for a specific column. For some reason, when I do

```
ws.find(item, in_column = 6)
```

it givens an

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

but when I do it with 2, it works fine. I tested it, and for any column 5 and over, it does not work. Anyone know why this is? I can send the full error message and code if needed.

Comment: Can you provide your sample Spreadsheet as an image?

Comment: I am not sure how to send an image, but here is the link to it:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10NWrdQURMkqQQR6odypuRpQvcysOMHMHiLlSiqdjg9c/edit#gid=1288556638

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could see your sample Spreadsheet. When I saw it, there are various sheets. In your question, what sheet did you test your script using? I would like to confirm the sheet for correctly replicating your issue of `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Comment: I iterated through all the sheets, here is my full code:
`cell = None
wslist = hoards.worksheets()
for ws in wslist:
    cell = ws.find(knife, in_column = 6)
    if (cell != None):
        worksheet = ws
        print("found cell")
        break`

Comment: Thank you for replying. What sheet did the error of `IndexError: list index out of range` occur at?

Comment: It should be at the second one, but I am not sure how to check. A quick search on the API reference doc didn't yield any results on how to get the worksheet name.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I checked your provided script using your sample Spreadsheet. By this, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tested all sheets in your sample Spreadsheet using `ws.find(item, in_column = 6)`, I confirmed that an error occurred on the 1st sheet ("Info" sheet). Also, I confirmed that in your 1st sheet of "Info", the merged cells are existing. In this case, it seems that such an error occurs.

If you are not required to use `ws.find(item, in_column = 6)` in the 1st sheet, as a simple modification, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

```py
cell = None
wslist = hoards.worksheets()
for ws in wslist:
    if ws.title != "Info":
        cell = ws.find(knife, in_column=6)
        if (cell != None):
            worksheet = ws
            print("found cell")
            break
```

- This script excludes the sheet using the sheet name "Info".

#### Modified script 2:

```py
cell = None
wslist = hoards.worksheets()
for i, ws in enumerate(wslist):
    if i > 0:
        cell = ws.find(knife, in_column=6)
        if (cell != None):
            worksheet = ws
            print("found cell")
            break
```

- This script excludes the sheet using the sheet index.

#### Note:

- This modified script can be used for your sample Spreadsheet. If your Spreadsheet is changed, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

Comment: @Nebula Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.